# How soon does REWRITE change to web.config take effect?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module

If I upload a new web.config file with a new REWRITE rule, how soon does that take effect?

I'd assume immediately.

Comment: Features like ARR depend on URL Rewrite module, so changes to the rules must take effect immediately. Otherwise, you cannot really use ARR as a reverse proxy (who wants to wait for a while).

Comment: What is ...ARR?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you are right. As soon as you uploaded a new `webconfig` or change the `URl Rewrite rules` in the `Rewrite` section, it would take effect immediately.
However, since the browser on the client-side prefer to cache the server response rules, the client have to fresh the browser forcibly(clear local cache) to apply the new rewrite rules.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I assume an F5 (in chrome)  would force a proper cache refresh of those new web.config rules, right?

Comment: Shift+F5. We have to ignore the local cache or we can browse it in a new private window.